# Why is pytorch softmax function not working?

Tags: python, pytorch

so this is my code

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch

inputs = [1,2,3]
input = torch.tensor(inputs)
output = F.softmax(input, dim=1)
print(output)
```

is the reason why the code not working because of the dim?
the error here:

```
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\AI\pytorch_jovian\linear_reg.py", line 19, in <module>
    output = F.softmax(input, dim=1)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1583, in softmax
    ret = input.softmax(dim)
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

Comment: exactly, your tensor `input` has a total of 1 dimensions, so only `dim=0` is valid with enumeration from 0

Comment: Well, of course it is because of the dim (and long). The error message says that. inputs is a one dimensional tensor. You want to apply the softmax to (or along) dimension 0. In Python and most of the other programming languages the first element of an array is indexed by 0, the 2nd element by 1 etc ..

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `dim=0`, there is another issue in your code. `Softmax` doesn't work on a `long tensor`, so it should be converted to a `float` or `double` tensor first

```
>>> input = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
>>> input
tensor([1, 2, 3])

>>> F.softmax(input.float(), dim=0)
tensor([0.0900, 0.2447, 0.6652])
```